# SQL Check for duplicated username in Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005. I want to form an SQL query with the following condition:

**Check for duplicated user in *Table1 tb1* where *tb1* has more than one [Emp.Name]**

**EDIT**:

Simply saying, if I am only checking duplicate for `[emp name]`, there's no way I can select `[employeeID]`?

Because if I use

```
INSERT INTO DuplicateUserInTb1(EmployeeID, [Emp Name], Status, Issue)
SELECT tb1.EmployeeID, tb1.[Emp Name], 'Active', 'Duplicated user in Table1'
FROM Table1 tb1 GROUP BY tb1.[employeeID], tb1.[emp name] HAVING COUNT(tb1.[emp name]) >1
```

I will not be able to see any duplicated `[emp name]` rows inserted.

However, if I use

```
INSERT INTO DuplicateUserInTb1([Emp Name], Status, Issue)
SELECT tb1.EmployeeID, tb1.[Emp Name], 'Active', 'Duplicated user in Table1'
FROM Table1 tb1 GROUP BY tb1.[emp name] HAVING COUNT(tb1.[emp name]) >1
```

I am able to retrieve duplicated `[emp name]`, however, without `[employeeID]`.

---

**EDITED:**

Working on these 2 queries provided by **Zohalib** and **Michal Powaga** respectively:

```
 INSERT INTO DuplicateUserInTb1(EmployeeID, [Emp Name], Status, Issue) 
 select t.emp_id, t.empname, t.active, t.du 
from (select s1.emp_id, s1.empname,'Active' as active, 'Duplicate User' as du,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.empName ORDER BY s1.empName) as rowNum 
from table s1, 
(select emp_name, count(*)
 from table 
 group by emp_name
 having count(*) > 1) s2
 where s1.emp_name = s2.emp_name 
) t where t.rowNum = 1
```

Error : *No column was specified for column 2 of 's2*

---

```
insert into DuplicateUserInTb1(EmployeeID, [Emp Name], Status, Issue)
select employeeID, [emp name], 'Active', 'Duplicated user in Table1'
from Table1 t1
join (
    select [emp name]
    from Table1
    group by [emp name]
    having count(*) > 1
) t on t1.[emp name] = t.[emp name]
```

Error: *`Ambiguous column name '[Emp name]'`

---

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: This query has 3 columns in the INSERT, but 4 in the SELECT?

Comment: My mistake. Edited: Added the additional column for the SELECT statement

Comment: You are inserting into and selecting from the same table. What are you trying to achieve? I thought you are moving them elsewhere.

Comment: simply do this
select employeeID, t.[emp name], 'Active', 'Duplicated user in Table1'

in second query  @user1084683

Comment: @user1084683 and for my query, you just need to mention the name for the column of count(*), do it like this. select (select emp_name, count(*) as counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Group By clause, then your select clause can only contain columns

> which are either mentioned in group by clause
>
> Or aggregate functions, eg Count, SUM e.t.c
> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Moreover, in your query, you are inserting values in three columns, but your select clause is selecting four values, should'nt this be a problem ?

try following query to insert duplicates based on empname

```
    INSERT INTO DuplicateUserInTb1(EmployeeID, [Emp Name], Status, Issue) 
select t.emp_id, t.empname, t.active, t.du 
from (select s1.emp_id, s1.empname,'Active' as active, 'Duplicate User' as du, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.empName ORDER BY s1.empName) as rowNum 
from table s1, 
(select emp_name, count(*) as counts
 from table 
 group by emp_name
 having count(*) > 1) s2
 where s1.emp_name = s2.emp_name 
) t where t.rowNum = 1
```

Comment: @Zohalib. My mistake, I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: @user1084683 shouldnt the problem be solved if you add other two columns in group by clause ?

Comment: @Zohalib in my sql for duplicate user check for table2, it has 2 variables in the GROUP by clause, so it is taking both the columns of `[EmployeeID]` and `[Emp Name]`, and checking them by pair for any duplicates. Now I would only want to take in `[Emp Name]` for duplicate check, so i assume i only need `GROUP BY tb2.[Emp Name]`?

Comment: @user1084683 No, If you use group by clause, then your select clause can only contain columns which are in group by clause, or aggregate functions, otherwise either dbms wont allow the query, or you will get unexpected results, depending on your dbms

Comment: @Zohalib ic. so simply saying, if i am only checking duplicate for `[emp name]`, there's no way i can select `[employeeID]` ? Because if I use `GROUP BY tb2.[employeeID], tb2.[emp name] HAVING COUNT(tb2.[emp name]) >1`, i will not be able to see any duplicated `[emp name]` rows inserted

Comment: @user1084683 have made some changes to query

Comment: @Zohalib thanks for the help. I have implemented ur statement but it gives me a whole list of users, which includes some which are not duplicated in `Table`

Comment: @RUiHAO Sorry, My bad, forgot to self Join, Idea is to join table with itself, and select rows such that empname exists in both, duplicate names will come out, now assign them row number, and select only 1 to insert i other table.

Comment: @RUiHAO I have edited the above sql query in the answer, I dont have dbms installed right now, so could not test the query.

Comment: @Zahalib thanks for the help. i still meet this error: `Ambiguous column name 'EmployeeID'.
Ambiguous column name '[Emp Name]'.
Ambiguous column name '[Emp Name]'.`

Comment: @RUiHAO I wish I had sql server installed at this machine. Its a minor error, as we have mentioned aliases with table names, we also need to mention alias in select clause. eg In inner query do this select s1.emp_id, s1.empname,'Active' as active, 'Duplicate User'

Comment: @Zahalib so the error simply means one or more variables are not tagged with a table which is to be retrieved from?

Comment: yes, since You have mentioned two tables in from clause, and both of these tables are same thus both have same columns with same name, so sql server does not know which column to select, simply add alias with column names in select clause. select s1.exp_id, s1.empName e.t.c. @RUiHAO

Comment: @RUiHAO I must be drunk or something, plz see the edited query in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into DuplicateUserInTb1(EmployeeID, [Emp Name], Status, Issue)
select t1.employeeID, t1.[emp name], 'Active', 'Duplicated user in Table1'
from Table1 t1
join (
    select [emp name]
    from Table1
    group by [emp name]
    having count(*) > 1
) t on t1.[emp name] = t.[emp name]
```

Comment: it gave me an error which says `Ambiguous column name '[Emp name]'.`

Comment: HI Michal Powaga, I have added SELECT DISTINCT as it is showing the same records for each duplicated user found. However, is there a way to match both of the same duplicated user found together? as the list of duplicated users found are scattered in the table. is it possible to sort them together by name?
if I don't put in the DISTINCT, each duplicated records found will be listed x6 times in the table. any idea why is it so?